# Javascript: Creating a Summary Object from a Series of Detail Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm iterating over a bunch of objects that look like this:

```
var tests = [{ date: 1379082017487,
  summary:
    {'Item A': 2069,
     'Item B': 8987,
     'Item C': 1890
    }},
{date: 1379082015968,
  summary:
    {'Item A': 1824,
     'Item B': 6758,
     'Item C': 3857
    }}];
```

I need to combine the data into a single object with the same keys, and arrays containing the combined values:

```
{ date: [1379082017487, 1379082015968],
  summary:
   { 'Item A': [2069, 1824],
     'Item B': [8987, 6758],
     'Item C': [1890, 3857]
   }
}
```

My strategy thus far is to create a nested loop; iterate over the top-level objects and add their values to a 'date' array.  Then iterate over the 'summary' object, pushing those values to an array representing each key.  In the end, I'd add the arrays back together to form my single output object.

My brain freeze is on the inner array.  It can have a varying number of keys ('Items').  While these keys will have the same names for all objects in any given run of the code, they can have different names between runs.  The inner loop isn't producing an array (like [2069, 1824]).

So far I have:

```
var testDates = [];
var itemVals = [];
// iterate over the outer objects
for (var record = 0; record < tests.length; record++) {
    testDates.push(tests[record].date); // this works fine

    // iterate over the inner 'summary' object:
    for (var itemName in tests[record]['summary']) {
        // doesn't produce the appropriate array
        itemVals.push([tests[record]['summary'][itemName]]);
    }

}
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a sample code for your problem. Please try this and let me know if it work

```
var tests = [{
  date: 1379082017487,
  summary: {
    'Item A': 2069,
    'Item B': 8987,
    'Item C': 1890
  }
}, {
  date: 1379082015968,
  summary: {
    'Item A': 1824,
    'Item B': 6758,
    'Item C': 3857
  }
}];
var json = {
  date: [],
  summary: {}
};
for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
  var dateJSON = tests[i];
  json.date.push(dateJSON.date);
  for (var key in dateJSON.summary) {
    if (dateJSON.summary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (json.summary[key] == null) {
        json.summary[key] = [];
      }
      json.summary[key].push(dateJSON.summary[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's actually perfect.  Just out of curiosity, JSLint says "use === to compare with null".  When I do that for `if (json.summary[key] === null)`, the line `json.summary[key].push(dateJSON.summary[key]);` fails with "TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined".  Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: when i used json.summary[key] === null, it returned me false so array was not initialized and hence got the error "cannot call 'push' of undefined". If i compare with (json.summary[key] === undefined) then it give me proper result i.e. true and array is initialized.